# How to install SIPp on Ubuntu 18.04 x64

Tags: sip

I am using this tutorial >> [SIPp install tutorial](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-the-sipp-testing-tool-on-ubuntu-server-18-04/)

I've reached this part.

```
./build.sh --with-pcap --with-sctp --with-openssl
```

But this is the error I get.

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/ubuntu/sipp/--with-openssl" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

Can anyone help me install SIPp and test it. I am using VMWARE but later I will try on Ubuntu server. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like new build.sh does not support same (--with-pcap --with-sctp --with-openssl) flags as before.

```
if test "$*" = "--none"; then
     cmake . -DUSE_GSL=
elif test "$*" = "--common"; then
     cmake . -DUSE_GSL=1 -DUSE_PCAP=1 -DUSE_SSL= -DUSE_SCTP=
elif test "$*" = "--full"; then
    cmake . -DUSE_GSL=1 -DUSE_PCAP=1 -DUSE_SSL=1 -DUSE_SCTP=1
else
    cmake . "$@"
fi
```

For pcap sctp and ssl support you can use:

```
./build.sh --full
```

For pcap support you can use:

```
./build.sh --common
```

Comment: I tried with version 16.04 of ubuntu and it worked. There is a solution on the net.